# getting textarea in bootstrap or jquery

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a form with typical inputs for name, address, age... using the standard textbox:

```
<input class="form-control" id="inputdefault" type="text">
```

For one of my inputs I require a bigger text area type control that I don't see a bootstrap version for and my UI looks to be not uniform.

Is there an element that is in line with the rest of the bootstrap textboxes as far as look and feel goes but allows for the input to be very wide (almost the entire form width) and tall(about 10x taller than a textbox)?

Answer (score 1):

```
   <textarea class="form-control" id="inputdefault" rows="4" cols="50">
   </textarea>
```

You could just use the HTML textarea tag and use the rows and cols to control the size yourself

`rows="#"` controls how may lines of text your box can hold and

`cols="#"` controls the width of the box

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`<textarea class="form-control">` 
It's inline with the other Bootstrap input types where you're probably using form-control as well.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has styling for a textarea. See: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#textarea.
Taking the example from the Bootstrap documentation, it's used like:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
```

Where the `rows` attribute determines how many lines of text it shows. In your case, it sounds like you might want something like:

```
<textarea class="form-control" rows="1"></textarea>
```